# What is this error in fortran and how to stop the program when it occurs?

Tags: fortran

I have a program that reads information from an input file. Since the code has nothing wrong, it can be successfully compiled. My question is even if there is reading error, the program is still running which is not a good thing when the program gets larger and hard for me to find out where the error occurs.

The program is:

```
program main

implicit none

integer ioerr, switch_1(3), switch_2, i

   open(100, FILE='./input_error.gr', ACTION='READ', IOSTAT=ioerr)
   if (ioerr == 0) then
     read(100,*) (switch_1(i), i=1,3)
     write(*,*) 'Switch_1 is: ', switch_1
     read(100,*) switch_2
     write(*,*) 'Switch_2 is: ', switch_2
   else
     write(*,*) 'File not read'
   end if

end program main
```

and the input file is:

```
1,2,3
3
```

and this works fine. But if the input file is:

```
1,2
```

I will get an reading error which I don't know what it is and want the program to stop every time this error occurs, and if possible gives me an error message like what I did for file opening:

```
forrtl: severe (24): end-of-file during read, unit 100, file /Users/ranranking/develop/test/switch_test/./input_error.gr
Image              PC                Routine            Line        Source
a.out              0000000107D1114E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000107D2D686  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000107D2B7D4  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000107CFAA30  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
a.out              0000000107CFA91E  Unknown               Unknown  Unknown
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your program reached the end of the file.  You can use the return code to identify the end-of-file condition and respond to it within your program.  Some code fragment to show an approach:

```
   use, intrinsic :: ISO_FORTRAN_ENV

   .....

   ReadFile: do

      read (data_LUN, '(A)', iostat=ReadCode)  line

      if ( ReadCode /= 0 ) then
         if ( ReadCode == iostat_end ) then
            write (*, *) "End of file"
            exit ReadFile    ! end of file -- exit read loop
         else
            write ( *, '( / "error reading the data file: ", I0 )' )  ReadCode
            stop
         end if
      end if

      read (line, *) .....

      ......

   end do ReadFile
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Can you tell me what is iostat_end?

Comment: `isostat_end` is the value of  the error end-of-file.  It is provided by the intrinsic module `ISO_FORTRAN_ENV`.  Otherwise each compiler might use a different numeric value and it would be difficult to test for this condition.