# Is it possible to limit recursive reading in one line?

Tags: fortran

Further question from my last post: [What is this error in fortran and how to stop the program when it occurs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464930/what-is-this-error-in-fortran-and-how-to-stop-the-program-when-it-occurs)

In my last post, I want to figure out how to identify the reading error when there is not enough elements in the input file which can be solved by using an iostat in the read statement.

My new code is:

```
program main

implicit none

integer ioerr, switch_1(3), switch_2, i, readerr

   open(100, FILE='./input_error.gr', ACTION='READ', IOSTAT=ioerr)

   if (ioerr == 0) then

     read(100, *, iostat=readerr) (switch_1(i), i=1,3)
     if(readerr .ne. 0) then
        write(*,*) 'switch 1 wrong'
        stop
     end if
     write(*,*) 'Switch_1 is: ', switch_1

     read(100,*,iostat=readerr) switch_2
     if(readerr .ne. 0) then
        write(*,*) 'switch 2 wrong'
        stop
     end if
     write(*,*) 'Switch_2 is: ', switch_2

   else
     write(*,*) 'File not read'
   end if

end program main
```

my input file looks like this:

```
1,2,3
1
```

My new question is when there is less than three elements in the first line, the program will automatically read elements in the next line for Switch_1 and Switch_2 will have nothing to read and as the program is coded, it will return "Switch 2 wrong". 
For example, when the input is like this:

```
1,3
2
```

However, what is really wrong is switch_1. Since there is not enough elements for switch_1, it goes to the next line the fill the last position of the array. This is not what I want. What I want is limit the reading in one line so the program will not read another line automatically, and in this case the program can stop at switch_1 and give me 'Switch 1 wrong. Is it possible?

Comment: How does this differ from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31464930/what-is-this-error-in-fortran-and-how-to-stop-the-program-when-it-occurs  ? You should reference your previous question and explain the difference otherwise you risk closing and downvoting.

Comment: Also explain which error you see. Does it print anything? Is the result wrong?

Comment: Thank you, I will add more details to my questions

Answer (score 1):

I typically solve this problem by reading the line into a string first, and then attempting to read numbers from the string. For example,

```
character(len=200) :: str    ! Long enough to hold a whole line
integer :: i(3), ier, fid

fid = 100
open(fid, FILE='./input_error.gr', ACTION='READ')

! -- Read a *single* line, and put it all into str
read(fid,'(a)') str

! -- Read str into integer array i
read(str,*,iostat=ier) i(1:3)

! -- Check if the line actually contained 3 integers
if (ier /= 0) then
    write(*,*) 'Unsuccessful read'
endif
```

The read statement is therefore only able to use the current line because that is all `str` contains.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! This is helpful but I think is a little too complicated when the program gets larger. Thank you again though

Comment: What are some other objectives you're looking for from the fix, then? My proposed solution adds only one extra line for each usual read call.

Comment: I figure out that if the program in dealing with numbers only, adding comments in the input file can solve my problem well. But I am not sure what will happen when I am dealing with character string input. Maybe I will have to use your approach in that case. I just want to keep the code as simple as possible

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that if I add a comment at the end of each line, since character a is different data type, it will not be read as integer numbers. The advantage is when there is not enough elements for each switches, the program will read the comment first instead of reading the next line and give the right error message.

For example, make the input like:

```
1,2,3         ! Switch 1
4             ! Switch 2
```

with this structure, even if there is not enough input elements for switch 1, it is not reading 4 as the third element, instead, it is reading the comment, "! Switch 1" which will definitely return an error for Switch 1. This is exactly what I want and this works fine with number reading procedures. However, if the data type of switch_1 is character in the beginning, what will happen? It will not stop at numbers.